# ejabberd admin interface is not open

Tags: macos, mac, network, xmpp

I'm newbie for XMPP/ejabberd. My system is "OS X EL Captain version 10.11.4" and As per my title said, I can't able to open **ejabberd admin interface.** 
When I click on **"admin interface"** not able to open admin panel.

For more clear look at below Images.

[image]

And when I click on "admin interface", display below error message.

[image]

I also do internet connect off Because I was thought issue might be problem is with fire-wall but same issue occurred.

[If you want to know how can installed "ejabberd" then look at this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655957/warning-ejabberd-can-not-start-admin-user-is-not-created-please-check-your-conf)

Can anybody knows the solution then please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Simply reinstall it and you can get rights to admin section.
it may be problem with config file.
If you have no error message from the installer, you should be set. You can call ejabberd start script to fictionalize
this helped me...

Comment: I tried by your way but didn't get success/

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall and Try Installing Ejabbered 16.06 instead
you can find it in ejabbered archives

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different – we're looking for posts that are in-depth and thorough. Could you please expand on your answer?